# gnuplot clustered histogram from different datafiles

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

So, I have files A and B, like:

```
# file A
# x  val
1     2
1.5   3
2     4
```

and

```
# file B
# x  val
1     3
1.5   5
2     7
```

How can I build a simple clustered histogram in gnuplot, so that each xtic has a bar for A and B's values at that point?

Basically, I want something like:

```
              B
              B
       B      B
       B     AB
 B    AB     AB
AB    AB     AB
AB    AB     AB
1     1.5     2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with:

```
set style fill solid
plot [0.5:][0:10] 'fileA' u 2: xtic(1) with histogram, 'fileB' u 2: xtic(1) with histogram
```

[image]